# Hide JS element without div or class

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to hide the toolbar of a SSRS report.

There is a specific reason why I need to use JS( The report will be included in the CRM 2011 Dashboard, and I wanted to remove the toolbar from the Report. Since the report parameters did not work, I imported Report Control solution and I am editing the viewer, which uses JS ). The viewer is a Html page that embeds the Report as an IFrame.
The generated Html code is:

```
<table id="reportViewer_fixedTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="table-layout:fixed;width:100%;height:100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="background-color:#C4DDFF;"> … </tr>
        <tr id="ParametersRowreportViewer" style="display:none;"> … </tr>
        <tr style="height:6px;font-size:2pt;display:none;"> … </tr>
        <tr>
```

The toolbar is in the 4th tr, and selecting it directly and trying to hide it did not work.

```
navCorrectorDiv = report.contentWindow.document.getElementById('reportViewer_Toolbar');
if (navCorrectorDiv != null) {
    navCorrectorDiv.style.display = "none";
}
```

I should select the table reportViewer_fixedTable, that I can do, then select the tbody element and then the fourth tr.
Is there a way to do it? Possibily without jQuery.

Comment: What exactly you want to hide.Elaborate a little

Comment: and where you will put the javascript to hide the toolbar in a crm dashboard?

Comment: Please post all your code so we can see where you are calling the Report. Also what solution did you import called "Report Control"? Can you provide a link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Case: No Iframe

Select the element

**As jQuery selector:**

```
var selected;
selected = jQuery('#reportViewer_fixedTable');
… 
selected = jQuery('#reportViewer_fixedTable tbody');
…
selected = jQuery('#reportViewer_fixedTable tr:nth-child(4)');
```

Hide selected with:

```
selected.css('display', 'none');
```

**or with modern browsers without jQuery:**

```
var selected;
selected = document.querySelector('#reportViewer_fixedTable');
…
selected = document.querySelector('#reportViewer_fixedTable tbody');
…
selected = document.querySelector('#reportViewer_fixedTable tr:nth-child(4)');
```

And hide:

```
selected.style.display = 'none';
```

## Case: Content in Iframe

The iframe can be problematic, because it might be sandboxed or the content might come from a different domain. This can lead into a XSS-violation which, in your case, might be unfixable.

Anyway, here we go:

```
//Select the first iframe (which might not be the right one in your case);
var elem = document.querySelector('iframe'); 

//And put it's body in a variable. We use the querySelector from the body 
//of the iframe.
var ibody = elem.contentWindow.document.body;

var table = ibody.querySelector('#reportViewer_fixedTable');
var tbody = ibody.querySelector('#reportViewer_fixedTable tbody');
var fourthtr = ibody.querySelector('#reportViewer_fixedTable tr:nth-child(4)');

table.style.display = 'none';
tbody.style.display = 'none';
fourthtr.style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: I will not down vote your answer, but it's "wrong". The problem is that the report will be executed inside a crm 2011 dashboard.

Comment: This is not working. Should the JS be different considering the table is located inside an IFrame?

Comment: user1648371: I added a separate section to solve the problem with content in an Iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do it by trying to find the [nth Chid](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

Consider this approach :

**HTML :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="reportViewer_fixedTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="table-layout:fixed;width:100%;height:100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="background-color:#C4DDFF;"> <td>1</td> </tr>
        <tr id="ParametersRowreportViewer" style="display:none;"><td>2</td> </tr>
        <tr style="height:6px;font-size:2pt;display:none;"> <td>3</td> </tr>
        <tr><td>FourthTR</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
console.log( $('#reportViewer_fixedTable tbody tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(1)').text());


  $('#reportViewer_fixedTable tbody tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(1)').addClass('FourthTR');
  $('.FourthTR').hide();
});
```

So , what we are trying to do is that, we are grabbing the 4th tr of the table and then we are grabbing the 1st child of the 4th tr. Once that is done, we are , on the fly, gonna add a class to it say `FourthTR` and then hide the class using `jQuery.hide()`. Voila, you are done.

See the working example here: http://jsbin.com/ACam/1/edit . As always, remember to `run with js` .

Comment: Are you sure , you have posted the correct HTML mark up in the question above ? Because i see  missing `td`s in the `tr`s.

Comment: The code was collapsed by Firefox's development tools, but I copy pasted from it. As I wrote as an answer to another proposal, does the fact that the code is inside an IFrame change the requirements?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use JavaScript for this

If you have access to ReportControl solution and server-side code of ReportViewer.aspx.cs, you can set property

```
reportViewer.ShowToolBar = false
```

in that code.

Alternatively, if you have access to and can modify viewer page markup (ReportViewer.aspx), you can set it declaratively: by adding `ShowToolBar="false"` to ReportViewer control declaration:

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="reportViewer" runat="server" ... ShowToolBar="false">
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

If this is not an option, you can amend URL you're passing to IFrame hosting ReportViewer, by adding `rc:Toolbar=false` parameter

```
http://localhost/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fMyReport%2fBEA&rs:Command=Render&rc:Toolbar=false
```

Comment: I cannot use the first two options. I think we are using two different version of SSRS: I do not have any ReportViewer.aspx page when I run the reports. I have a Viewer.aspx.

Comment: You might be right, but it could be similar thing - a viewer page should have a viewer control - does it have anything similar to markup shown above? Can you post that page markup if its not too long? Also, what about 3rd option - were u able to pass URL parameter?

Comment: I have tried with every possible parameter, the Viewer is simply ignoring them. I have a "too long by 59507 characters" message when I try to paste the rendered Viewer code

Comment: What about ASPX page itself? Does it contain ReportViewer control?

Comment: I found many references to the ReportViewerWebControlHandler in the rendered page. I do not have access to the original ASPX

Comment: My bad, I thought you have Report Control solution and editing the Viewer code. If you don't you can try URL Access: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153586.aspx to send commands to viewer directly to alter look and feel